# Parse Filezilla log with awk, IP and Logins

Tags: regex, awk, filezilla

I am trying to extract a list of username's and the IP addresses they logged in from out of a FileZilla log.

```
(000099) 11/29/2013 9:20:26 AM - user_one (145.194.40.65)> 230 Logged on
```

I have already gotten a list of all IP's that have had a valid login by using this:

```
cat FileZilla\ Server.log | grep "Logged on" | awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print ip}' | sort | uniq -c
```

But how can I match both the username and the IP address?  So the output would look something like this when finished:

```
5 user_one 10.1.1.1
3 user_one 10.5.1.1
2 user_two 10.1.1.1
3 user_two 10.8.8.8
```

I've spent a few hours on this one, so any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I won't post this as answer as I don't know `awk`, but you can go with this regex: `\(\d+\) \d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} .. - (\w+) \((\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\)`

Comment: What is the number in front of the user name in your expected output? Ok I see, it comes from `uniq`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following command:

```
gawk -f a.awk FileZilla\ Server.log
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
/Logged on/{
    match($0,/[0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] .. . ([^ ]*) \(([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\)/,a)
    b[(a[1]" "a[2])]++
}
END {
    for (i in b) {
        print b[i], i
    }
}
```

If you want to sort the result, it can be done in Gnu Awk version 4, using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` as

```
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
    for (i in b) {
        print b[i], i
    }
}
```

Comment: `$ awk -f a.awk FileZilla\ Server.log 
    awk: a.awk: line 2: syntax error at or near ,`

Looked at line two and I couldn't find anything wrong with it.  But then, I'm not an awk expert.

Comment: @BryanLee Interesting.. I can not see anything wrong either.. What happens, if you replace the `match` with `match($0,/user/,a)`?

Comment: turned out I needed to use gawk, not awk.  I'm on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @BryanLee Great! Note that a third argument to the `match` function is specific to Gnu Awk.. (That is: the array `a` is only recognized if you use `gawk`)

Comment: Yup, I saw that after I erroneously tried to use just 'awk'.  Thank you!!